# Java Xml Transformer does not close opened files leading to "Too many open files error" on Linux OS

Tags: java, linux, xslt, saxon

We are working on a Java 8 legacy software.

We are using xslt transform to present .xml files in .html format.

Our issue is that our .xsl styleSheet file imports some other .xsl file.

(All the code down below is dumbed down because I cannot give the real code...)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

    <xsl:import href="someTemplate.xsl"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

[...]
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then we are transforming our .xml datasource using this .xsl stylesheet and `net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory` as our source for `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`.

Saxon pom dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
    <version>9.7.0-14</version>
</dependency>
```

`net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory` is instanciated as follow:

```java
TransformerFactoryImpl transformerFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();

    Path targetFolderPath = <some Path>;
    transformerFactory.setURIResolver((arg0, arg1) -> {

      try
      {
        InputStream xslStream = Files.newInputStream(targetFolderPath.resolve(arg0));
        return new StreamSource(xslStream);
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        return null;
      }
    });
```

Our .xsl stylesheet if opened inside a try-with-resource.

```java
try (InputStream xslStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(pathToTheXslFile));)
    {

      Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslStream));
      
      transformer.transform(XmlData, new StreamResult(destFile));
       
    }
    catch (IOException | TransformerException e)
    {
      [some logs...]
    }
```

our issue is that the transform seems to open the file imported by the .xsl stylesheet without ever closing it.

This result in a "Too many open files error" when working on Linux OS.

Basically we are completely stumped by this issue since `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` does not offer any Autocloseable option and we do not seem to have any access to the opened files.

What we thought of was to make some custom code to force files closing through Linux command Line.

**EDIT**:

Reading the code after my latest update of the description, I see it now...

We did not implementent a Try-with-resource when creating the URIResolver for our TransformerFactory.

I will make the change, test it and then close the question if it does work (it should... ;)).

Thx for the comments.

**EDIT2**:

Adding try-with-resource to the URIResolver lambda expression results in `net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: I/O error reported by XML parser processing null: null`
This is due to the fact that the `InputStream` used to create the `StreamSource` is closed as soon as the `StreamSource` is returned, rendering it useless.

Comment: Can you close file descriptors of another process? I would expect not. What is the implementation library that you are using for Transformer?

Comment: Check your user limits.  If you are already at unlimited, then the code - library is buggy and is crashing the system.

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using? I would normally assume the default one built into the JDK, but you specify version="2.0", and the default processor only supports XSLT 1.0.

Comment: It does not surprise me as xml parser had similar problems. However, how did you confirm that it is the xsl file handles rather than some other part of the application?

Comment: @DuncG we suppose that _Transformer_ is the issue because it is the method _transform_ is the only one manipulating our .xsl. Nowhere can we find any direct read of the unclosed files.

Comment: @Michael Kay as stated in my question, we are using basic javax xml Transformer. The transformation itself does work. Our only issue is with imported files that are not closed.

Comment: @TonioLeParigo Try running `lsof` to confirm file handle usage, grep by your jvm pid.

Comment: 'This result in a "Too many open files error" when working on Linux OS under certain conditions.': what exactly are the certain conditions?

Comment: @DuncG we did that when the error occured and we confirmed that it was indeed the sames files that were kept opened by the JVM. Moreover, we did see that it was the same files that were opened over and over again.

Comment: @Martin Honnen. The conditions are during integration tests that do call for transform over and over in quick succession. That how we saw the issue but there is no reason that it would not happen in prod after a while. I will remove the line about « conditions » since it might be misleading.

Comment: @TonioLeParigo The javax `Transformer` is an interface, not a class. There are several different implementations. If you weren't aware of that, I guess we should infer that you are using the default implementation that comes with the JDK.

Comment: You could try nominating a user-written URIResolver to handle the include/import requests. Your URIResolver could (for example) read the specified file into a byte array and then return a ByteArrayInputStream over this byte array (wrapped in a StreamSource); it then wouldn't matter that this doesn't get closed. Or, just for diagnostics, you could return a Stream which you monitor for a call on close(), just to confirm that the stream really is never closed.

Comment: @Michael Kay. Reading the code, I see it now... We indeed are using net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory for our factory. Moreover, I do think that we did not take into account how our factory was intanciated. I'll change the description.

Comment: As this is turning into a Saxon issue, consider to add information as to which Saxon version exactly you are using.

Comment: Saxon 9.7 is rather old and beyond its support but I am not sure for JAXP it matters. The samples section has one example of a URI resolver in https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/repository/he/revisions/master/entry/latest9.7/samples/java/he/JAXPExamples.java#L1105 and https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/repository/he/revisions/master/entry/latest9.7/samples/java/he/JAXPExamples.java#L1079, not sure whether will help you for your code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bug https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3401

which was fixed in Saxon 9.7.0.21 and later releases.

It's a good idea to keep up to date, at least with maintenance releases if not with major releases. Saxon 9.7 dates back to 2017.

In the bug entry there's also a link to a tool that I used for diagnosis - you might find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of your input, we found the issue and came up with a correction (indeed close to recommendation of @MichaelKay comment).

Basically, we did implement our own `URIResolver` that implement a `close()` method that we then call into a `finally` clause.

CustomUriResolver:

```java
ublic class CustomUriResolver implements URIResolver
{

  private Path folderPath;


  private List<InputStream> inputStreamList = new ArrayList<>();


  public CustomUriResolver(Path folderPath)
  {
    super();
    this.folderPath = folderPath;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException
  {
    try
    {
      InputStream xslStream = Files.newInputStream(folderPath.resolve(href));
      inputStreamList.add(xslStream);
      return new StreamSource(xslStream);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  public void closeStreams() throws IOException
  {
    for (InputStream is : inputStreamList)
    {
      is.close();
    }
  }

}
```

Usage for XSLT transform:

```java
    TransformerFactoryImpl transformerFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();

    ReportUriResolver uriResolver = new ReportUriResolver(getReportXslFolderPath());

    transformerFactory.setURIResolver(uriResolver);

    try
    {
      xsltTransformation(transformerFactory, xmlDocument);
    }
    finally
    {
      try
      {
        // close streams opened during XSL transform with imports
        uriResolver.closeStreams();
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
      }
    }
```